# How to set focus to Desktop Icons?

Tags: 18.04, xfce

I would like to use arrow keys to scroll focus between Desktop Icons ( such as Trash , MyhomeFolder etc. ) without the help of mouse --- Currently I had to click with a mouse before the arrow keys take effect.

Is it possible to config Ubuntu to put the focus to any desktop icons by default ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Minimize all - `Win` + `D`
2. Type the name of the icon you want to go to. This will select those which match.
3. `Escape` releases the selection and allows you to type again.

Unfortunately this still doesn't allow navigation with arrows. I consider that a regression. Maybe file a feature request?